# Export "Data flow Task" task result to "text file" in ssis

Tags: ssis

I would like export result obtained from "Data flow Task" to a "Text" file with **"^"** delimited format.

But in the Flat file connection manager I don't see that delimiter option. Please suggest. I am okay with any different way of getting the result in the mentioned format through SSIS.

Thanks in advance.

-Manoj Gade

Comment: could you show the data derived from data flow task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

go to Flat File Connection Manager for Your output file. Then go to "Advanced" tab. Select every column aside from the last one (this is important!) and just type ^ in "ColumnDelimeter" property. Drop down list will present You with few suggestions, but still You can type the property malually. Hope that helps!

Comment: This is really helpful and worked. Thanks much! @white-raven